# Tangent cone of a complete intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a quasi projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. By the tangent cone of $X$ at a point $p \in X$,  I mean the subvariety of the tangent space of $X$ at $p$ as it is defined in Harris' "Algebraic Geometry: A first course" (Lecture 20). In particular, the tangent cone is a *reduced* subscheme.

Now let $X$ be locally around $p$ a complete intersection. I wonder whether the tangent cone at $p$ is also a complete intersection. If this is really the case, I would be glad for a reference. Otherwise I would be grateful for a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the *wrong* definition of tangent cone, then certainly there are counterexamples.  For instance, for the origin $p=(0,0,0)$ in $\mathbb{A}^3$, consider the curve $$X=\text{Zero}(\ s(t+u) + f(s,t,u),\ tu + g(s,t,u)\ ),$$ where $f$ and $g$ are sufficiently general polynomials of high degree.  The tangent cone is the complete intersection $$\text{Zero}(\ s(t+u), \ tu \ ).$$  However, the underlying reduced scheme of this nonreduced complete intersection is $$\text{Zero}(\ tu,\ su, \ st \ ),$$ which is *not* a complete intersection.

Comment: thank you. so you are saying that this definition of tangent cone is "wrong". is there a "right" definition such that the answer to my question becomes yes? is the "wrong" tangent cone of a complete intersection perhaps always a set-theoretic complete intersection?

Comment: @Hans: in this article, Keith Kendig shows: if the intersection of the tangent cones of two varieties is proper, then that intersection is the tangent cone of the intersection of the varieties.  Is that what you want?  https://eudml.org/doc/161952

Comment: The point is that for your questions to have answer yes, one needs a hypothesis on the dimension of the intersection of the cones.  Then it seems to be yes in both senses.

Comment: @Hans: The example given in this answer, from notes of Milne, seems to be an example of a complete intersection curve of two surfaces whose (correct) tangent cone is apparently not a complete intersection.  Of course the hypothesis on the intersection of the tangent cones of the two surfaces being a curve, is violated. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114128/about-the-tangent-cone-and-tangent-space-of-an-affine-variety?rq=1